# access different item types from anonymous array

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

A function returns an object, with an object member filled with an anonymous array of items; how do I get back the individual items?

the object that is returned from a function:

```
public class FunctionCallResult
{
   ...blah blah members...
    public object ResultObject { get; set; }
}
```

The function:

```
FunctionCallResult SomeCrazyFunction(string irrelevant_param1, int some_other_irrelevant_param2)
{
    ... some heavy duty code that raises eyebrows ...
    return new FunctionCallResult{ new object[] { SomeCrazyClassX, AnotherCraxyClassY } };
}
```

An example call of function:

```
var myresult = SomeCrazyFunction( "I am the walrus", 42);
```

But now, how do I get back the individual objects, which are of different classes?

```
// can't do this... can't index type of object
SomeCrazyClassXType classX = myresult.ResultObject[0];
AnotherCraxyClassYType classY = myresult.ResultObject[1];
```

So...how can I get these different class types out of the result returned?

Comment: Anonymous types doesn't really apply here.  An anonymous type is something like `var t = new { A=1, B=2 };`

Comment: In your example, you have 2 ints in an anonymous array. My example just has different members than int's. Why is my example not an anonymous array? What would you call it?

Comment: What I mean is, in my class, there is an 'object' member; so is "new object [] { ... , ... }" fundamentally different from "new [] { ... , ... }" ?

Comment: Note that my example doesn't have `[]`.  [see this for syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)  An anonymous type is not bound to a name.*  Your array doesn't have an anonymous type.  It's type is Object.  There may be a boxing or reference conversion involved, but the array is still composed of named types. (Note from above: the anonymous type has a name, but the compiler doesn't tell you what it is directly, and you can't use it to instantiate the type.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you "know" `ResultObject` is an `object[]` at runtime and the number of items in it and you know their types, you could cast them to `SomeCrazyClassXType` and `AnotherCraxyClassYType` after casting `ResultObject` to an `object[]` from `object`.

So:

```
var resultObjectAsAnObjectArray = (object[])myresult.ResultObject;
var classX = (SomeCrazyClassXType)(resultObjectAsAnObjectArray[0]);
var classY = (AnotherCraxyClassYType)(resultObjectAsAnObjectArray[1]);
```

I'd have to see more code/what you're actually doing to give a better recommendation.

Comment: If he knows the order (and then inherently the size) then it's better to create a Tuple.

Comment: While it worked just fine, (and thank you!) I will suggest a Tuple

Comment: @Gusman I agree that would be better - to be fair the question was, specifically, how do I get back the individual objects - I was just trying to change the least amount of code as possible and answer the question.